Is it compulsory that I get an invitation to Russia?
Is it mandatory that I use an invitation to Russia for multiple entry business visas? Can't I say I want to come to Russia to seek people who sell inverters and import from them, and provide the necessary documentations and all, and apply for a Business / Tourist visa once and for all?

What's your citizenship?

Did you try to contact the Russian embassy in your country of residence (or visa application), or perhaps look at their website?

How are you going to find those people who sell inverters? Why could you not do the same from your location? Why in Russia?

If you book an hotel, AFAIK you get an invitation. Or if you use a Russian travel agency you get also one. The visiting company may also write you an invitation. It is not much formal

AFAIK the necessary documentation includes an invitation. What else do you have in mind?

Yes, it's compulsory. All types of visas for Russia, even tourist visas, require letter of invitation. (Update: e-Visas do not, but they're single entry and limited to nationals of 55 states.)
The good news is that it's just a pointless piece of bureaucracy, there are companies like iVisa that issue these to anybody for around US$20, no questions asked. (Mentioning them by name because I've used them and they were fine, but there are plenty of other options.)

https://electronic-visa.kdmid.ru/index_en.html E-visa does not need an invitation which is an explicit bullet point.

@alamar OP wants a multiple entry business visa, and we don't know if their citizenship qualifies for an e-Visa.
