Do I need Letter of invitation to Iceland?
I want to go for tourism purposes to a country come Next year. Since I was not getting something good with Russia (coupled with the fights there), can I go to Iceland as a tourist without invitation (just booking my hotel and itinerary in this case)? I am Nigerian.

I find it weird that you initially wanted to go to Russia for business, and now "instead" apparently, you want to go to Iceland for tourism.

@jcaron Where does it say the visit to Russia was for business?

@Relaxed OP's previous question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/192205/is-it-compulsory-that-i-get-an-invitation-to-russia "Multiple entry business visas" ... "seek people who sell inverters and import from them"... Though it was already fuzzy "apply for a Business / Tourist visa once and for all"

It's not clear from your question if you are aware of it, but the first thing you'll need is a passport, and the second thing you'll need is a visa (for the Schengen Area, but issued by or on behalf of Iceland if the main destination of your trip is Iceland).
Note that Iceland has no presence in Nigeria, so you will actually need to apply with the consulate or embassy or another Schengen country who will process the visa application. In Nigeria, it's the Norwegian embassy in Kenya (!), but you have to apply via VFS Global, and they have offices in Abuja and Lagos.
Contrary to some other countries (like Russia), you do not need an invitation letter to get a visa for tourism purposes, unless a citizen or resident of Iceland actually invites you and you will be staying at their place, etc.
You will however need quite a bit of paperwork. The details may vary on your circumstances, you'll find the details on the VFS website and more specifically here in the case of a tourist visa, but more or less you'll need to provide:

Your itinerary, including hotel bookings and possibly flight bookings. Flight bookings need to be confirmed, they do not need to be paid. If you pay for them, make sure they are fully refundable.
Proof of your financial situation, including bank statements for the last 3 months, payslips, work contract, and approval from your employer (documents will vary if you are self-employed or other non-salaried situations). This is meant to show both that:

You can afford the trip.
You have a good reason to go back home (you won't overstay in Iceland or elsewhere in the Schengen Area and try to work illegally, or claim asylum, or whatnot).


Other documentation regarding your personal/family situation.

Remember that sadly Nigeria has one of the highest rates of refusal, so:

Make sure you do provide all the required documentation, and that it's all valid and consistent (both between documents and with your stated goal).
Do not waste time applying for a visa if you do not have a stable situation and income or savings appropriate for the cost of your trip and not ridiculously low compared to incomes in Iceland.
For reference, the average monthly salary in Iceland is nearly 8 million Naira.

Do not provide any false documentation. Make sure that if you use the services of an "agent", they are reputable, and double check everything they will submit. If they submit anything that is fake or otherwise wrong, you are the one who will be held responsible, and you are the one who will be banned from the whole Schengen Area for years. Note that there is no requirement and probably no valid reason to use an agent.

Consular officers who examine applications are used to seeing all sorts of terrible applications, especially in Nigeria. They will start with a negative bias. You must convince them that you are someone who will come spend money in the country and then go back home on time.


Note that Iceland is a very expensive country. They are the third most expensive country in the world according to Statista.

Note your link in the last paragraph redirects (for a non-subscriber?) to www.statista.com splash, not the specific page you linked.  It might be better to summarize the data briefly in the answer.

@user4556274 it seems to work the second time you click on it, weird.

NB: the page linked in your final paragraph only lists selected countries, so one cannot conclude from those data alone that Iceland is the third most expensive country (it is certainly very expensive, in particular Reykjavík, but absolute comparisons are hard as it depends on what one spends money on).

I get that Iceland is a small country that may not bother with a consular prescense in Nigeria. But surely there's something closer than Kenya as an alternative!

@CMaster It used to be (until last month) Accra in Ghana, but things have been moved to Nairobi (note that this is not even Iceland but Norway... Iceland process visa applications themselves in only 5 or 6 countries in the world!). Since most interactions with the applicant are done by VFS (who has local presence in Nigeria), I'm not sure it matters much, really. I'm pretty sure that with the increased outsourcing to VFS and the like, many countries are actually moving the decision-making back "home" anyway. The real question is who is actually putting the stickers in the passports.
